# Javascript events multiple calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i'm experiencing a very strange issue for the first time.
I'm developping a website with many ajax calls (my ajax calls load html tables, widgets, navbar etc..), on some ajax responses i include sepecific javascript used by the loaded content (fold/unfold tbody for exemple).

for example, on my table, i include the following code :

```html
$(document).on("click",".foldandunfold i", function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-right");
    $(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down");
    $(this).parents("tbody:first").find("tr:not(:first)").toggle();
});
```

When a second ajax call is send, returning other content (with same javascript) my jquery event runs twice, if i load another table, it runs three times etc..

Moving the javascript to a lower part of my website resolve the issue (because it's loaded only 1 time, but i have dynamicly generated javascript (using php) that is widget specific, i can'nt move it outside the ajax response.

Can i tell jquery or JIT javascript compiler to clean this event or something like that ?

Sorry for my english :x

Comment: Looks like this script is in your ajax callback, move it to your document ready callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use `off()` to remove all events on the element: [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

```
$(document).off().on("click",".foldandunfold i", function (e) {
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-right");
        $(this).toggleClass("fa-chevron-down");
        $(this).parents("tbody:first").find("tr:not(:first)").toggle();
    });
```

You can also remove it just for the event or element you want:

```
$(document).off("click",".foldandunfold i");
```

**By the way:** Consider to take another element than `$(document)`, because jQuery will have to look over the whole document every time your AJAX-Call is finished and you rebind the event. When you use for example `$('table.myDynamicTable').on(...)` it will just have to look up the DOM inside the table and it will run faster.

Comment: It works ! using $('table.myDynamicTable').on(...) doesn't work for me, because 'table.myDynamicTable' is loaded by ajax, the only way i found it to work is to use a larger scope (document or body), i'm right ?

Comment: Don't know exactly your code. But your table will be appended to a dom elment (for example a div)? Then add a id to this div and use this instead of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `e.stopPropagation();` to the end of your handler.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/